# Term for men in their twenties or thirties?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term for men in their twenties and thirties?  I'm specifically asking in the context of men although I imagine there might be a gender neutral adjective.

- "Young man" seems like it could encompass teenagers.
- "Young adult man" seems the same
- "Post-adolescent" seems again teenager-ish
- "Pre-middle age"?

This is for an academic research project that describes the lives of men who are out of high-school (and maybe college) but before they marry (hopefully) in their mid-late 30s. The student is using "men in their twenties and thirties" but we were hoping there was something more succinct.

Comment: Doesn’t it seem like “before they marry in their mid-late 30s” is dreadfully full of invalid assumptions?

Comment: Yes, some men don't marry into their 40s 50s 60s and so forth.

Comment: @RoboKaren And a **lot** of men marry in their twenties, some even in their teens.

Comment: Seems like the point is “single adult males” rather than any particular upper age bound.  I.e., “out of high school = adult, before they marry = single.”

Comment: Her sample doesn't include middle aged men (40s-50s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia, "young adult"hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult_(psychology)) for psychologists is in the neighborhood of 20-39/40 year-olds, which would fit your student's population fairly well. There is clearly some variability; in addition to that pointed out in the article, for example, the American Psychological Association considers 18-29 to be the *young adult* age group, and 30-39 is called *thirties*, in its [PsycINFO database](http://proquest.libguides.com/psycinfo/fields). However, I think if the term were defined up front, it would be well understood (and clearly does not include younger teens).

I would therefore suggest **Young adult males** (this sounds better to me than **young adult *men***, since the sexes are generally divided into *male* and *female*—see "Population" in the document linked above).

Comment: And you can vary it and also say "male young adults", "young male adults" and "young males".

Answer (score 0):

'Tricenarian' probably is the word for a person of age between 30-39.